# For the past 2 millenia, have the mantras of the Vedas been chanted wrong?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, brahmanas, samhita, krishna-yajurveda

My doubt arises from this article https://lrc.la.utexas.edu/books/rigveda/RV00

Also the Tāittirīya-saṁhitā́ contains both mántra-s (poëtry written in meter) and yájus-es and brā́hmaṇa-s (prose not written in a meter): the latter doesn't need metrical restoration, while the former does.
As an example, we have the following mántra (in the tri-ṣṭúbh) from TS 1.1.14.1–2:

Şúciṁ nú stómaṁ • náva-jātam adyá

Índrā-Agnī • vr̥tra-haṇā juṣéthām.

Ubhā́ hí Vāṁ • su-hávā jóhavīmi

tā́ vā́jaṁ sadyá • uşaté dháyiṣṭhā.

But the Tāittirīya-saṁhitā́ has instead ady' Éndr'-Āgnī (missing two syllables) and dhéṣṭhā (missing a syllable).

Also https://twitter.com/EEsanH/status/1632851872745660416

If this is true, then what are the implications of this? Does this mean all the mantras chanted in the past 2 millennia were chanted with errors?

***I'm not stating that we are reciting the mantras wrong, I am wondering if we are reciting them wrong***

Comment: it is pointless to argue english translations of ancient sanskrit mantras. go to a real veda patashala if interested - one of the 6 veda angas (shiksha) deals with exact pronunciation

Comment: @mar How is this about English translations? To me it seems like metrical restoration is necessary. For example the original Rudram is much different than the reformulated one (maybe by Baudhayana).

Comment: different shakas in india have different recessions and methods of chanting. purusha suktam sounds much different in south and north. there are also error-correction methods of chanting inbuilt into ghana recitation. if u r truly serious, veda patashala are the subject matter experts.

Comment: I (and most vedic students) have been specifically warned not to read/learn Vedas by book and definitely not English transliterations. At best, they can serve as memory aid after learning is over. It is like learning formula for radioactive material from quora articles. the potential for danger is high. so it is actually a tapasya or service to actively refrain from reading Vedas from unauthentic sources.

Comment: @mar yeah I'm not reading the Vedas currently